# .gitignore does not ignore config.codekit

Tags: git, gitignore, codekit

## Description of the problem

I have `config.codekit` listed inside my project's `.gitignore` file, but changes to `config.codekit` are still tracked by git.

## Steps to reproduce the problem

1. create a new project, initialize git, and add the project to CodeKit
2. make the first commit
3. add `config.codekit` to the project's `.gitignore` file
4. do `$ git status` and see that `.gitignore` is listed under **Changes not staged for commit**, as expected
5. *(optionally commit again here, but the problem persists even without committing)*
6. affect `config.codekit` by opening CodeKit and changing project settings, such as adding a directory to **Skipped Items & Paths**. alternatively you can manually edit or even delete `config.codekit`
7. Open `config.codekit` (if it hasn't been deleted) and mentally note the changes made
8. do `$ git status` and see that, along with `.gitignore`, `config.codekit` is listed under **Changes not staged for commit**.

## Expected result

`config.codekit` should not be listed anywhere when checking git status.

Comment: During your steps to reproduce the problem, does `config.codekit` ever get committed at all, or is it never a part of the repo aside from a line in the `.gitignore`?

Comment: Looks like config.codekit is already in git index. If so, you can remove it from git (git rm config.codekit), then commit it, then the file will not track.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister `config.codekit` has already been in the commit history. I've edited my question to clarify. thanks.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister — I'm confused, I thought changes to files listed in .gitignore (even if those files are already tracked by git) were still ignored.

Comment: @chharvey That is indeed not the case, and I think it's the heart of your question. `.gitignore` only prevents untracked files from being added, it does not prevent files that have already been added from continuing to be tracked.

Answer (score 2):

Try `git rm --cached <file>`